# Restoring position of RecyclerView to same as before after switching activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle

I am using **RecyclerView** in my application and want to achieve that whenever I switch to another activity my position of recyclerView activity should be stored and when I come back from another activity to RecyclerView activity it should be on same position where it was left. please help.

I am using Android Studio.

**RecyclerView class file:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        mrecyclerView = (RecyclerViewPager) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(HomePage.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        layout.setReverseLayout(true);//<---- to get new posted data on top of list
        layout.setStackFromEnd(true);//<-----
        mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
}
```

**recyclerView xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="andromeda.petrochemical.HomePage">




    <com.lsjwzh.widget.recyclerviewpager.RecyclerViewPager
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:rvp_singlePageFling="true"
        app:rvp_triggerOffset="0.1" />
```

**Source code:**

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity{


        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private RecyclerViewPager mrecyclerView;
        private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
        public static int recyclerPos = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("System");
        mrecyclerView = (RecyclerViewPager) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(HomePage.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        layout.setReverseLayout(true);
        layout.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            sentToStart();
        }

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

                post.class,
                R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
                postViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setsource(model.getSource());
            }
        };
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }


    public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title){
            TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.title_cardView);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }
        public void setsource(String source){
            TextView post_source = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.source_cardView);
            post_source.setText(source);
        }
    }
        private void sentToStart() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, LoginPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings){
            Intent intentSettings = new Intent(HomePage.this,settings.class);
            startActivity(intentSettings);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) mrecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
            recyclerPos = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mrecyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerPos);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156433/discussion-on-question-by-rohit-b-restoring-position-of-recyclerview-to-same-as). If you want to answer the question, *post an answer*.

Comment: remove the code in onResume(). and try

Comment: @war_Hero nope, nothing happens, same problem

Comment: Bro post your complete code I will go through and help you out Tom

Comment: @war_Hero all of the code is already posted here

Comment: ok will look into it

Comment: @war_Hero  you found anything useful brother?

Comment: I have not yet gone through, will tell you by tomorrow, as I am busy today

Comment: @war_Hero okay bro, thanks